# How to toggle torch functionality in iPhone 4 iOS 6 at app start with preferences plist

Tags: ios

I'm using an app called "Stickam", which is live audio/video recording and upload over 3G. The app is perfect for my purpose except for lacking LED torch (flashlight) mode. I have a tweak installed which allows me to toggle on torch via settings and leave it on while I use other apps (i.e., Safari, Appstore) but when I start a Stickam broadcast, the torch turns off.

I'm using a file browser on the iPhone with basic text editing and file manipulation ability to examine the iOS file structure and the apps. I don't want to edit Stickam, just override it's setting by pasting in Stickam's 
`var/mobile/Applications/FA037A73-C483-43D6-8AE8-7E69CD57EBDD/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`, a reference to torch's location and trigger.
Similar to:

```
<dict>
<key>cell</key>
<string>PSSwitchCell</string>
<key>default</key>
<false/>
<key>alternateColors</key>
<true/>
<key>defaults</key>
<string>com.ravirajm.torch</string>
<key>key</key>
<string>torchenabled</string>
<key>label</key>
<string>Enable Torch</string>
<key>PostNotification</key>
<string>com.ravirajm.torch/prefs</string>
</dict>
```

Doesn't seem like it would work. What ideas do you have on how to do this?

Comment: You only want to go with preference plist ? Because by the code it's simple : AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        [device setTorchMode: onOff ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask the developer to add the feature.

Comment: Do you have MobileSubstrate installed? Why not hook the application's method's to add the code instead of doing it through a plist?

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify another developer's app bundle at all unless the device is jailbroken.